# Java desktop application is not under project name in my IDE

Tags: ide, desktop-application

I am using a tutorial and it show there is a java desktop application under the project option in his IDE (after click on new project the new project page will open and under java category there is a java desktop application) . And I should chose it in my IDE and it is not there.why it is not there?what i should do to have it?
my IDE version is 7.3 . and in tutorial he is using version 6. 
I will appreciate your answer .

Answer (score 0):

You have actually answered your own question without realizing it.  The reason that Java Desktop Application is not in your version of Netbeans (making an assumption here based on prior experience with this exact issue) is because it was deprecated as of version 7.1.  Though it is more complex, you might want to look into learning [how to use the Netbeans Platform](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html) instead as it is considered the replacement for what used to be labeled a Java Desktop Application in Netbeans.